# Serve different images to different user agents using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, responsive-design

I am planning to build a responsive website. Though I want the images to look good on all devices without having to change the content.

Is there a way to serve different images to different user agents or screen resolutions, using only htaccess?

For example have two folders "/images" and "/imagesiphone" and if user agent is ihpone it sends images from imagesiphone istead of images (of course I would have to duplicate all the images in the folder "imagesiphone").

Would there be any spam reactions if you send different content for the same requested image?

Note: I dont want to use any javsacript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}  ^.*iPhone.*
RewriteRule ^images/(.*)$ imagesiphone/$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for the code Flash Thunder! Do you know if it is posibble to serve different images to different screen sizes as well? Or any other good ways to find out when to serve highresolution images... :)

Comment: `HTTP request` doesn't contain any information about screen resolution. The only way, would be to use `javascript` to convert image links based on `screen.width` and `screen.height` variables.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to find a list with all user agents that need highresolution images then :)